# Bash script for updating part of XML element value

Tags: xml, linux, bash, macos, xmlstarlet

I need a bash script for updating part of XML element value according to some other dynamic property.

For example, the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <Configure class="org.eclipse.something">
   <Set name="foo">foo-val</Set>
   <Set name="bar">bar-val</Set>
   <Set name="my-elm">/dont/matter/THIS_ONE_NEED_TO_BE_UPDATED</Set>
 </Configure>
```

Tried to use xmlstarlet with regexing, but it's not providing the result I want.
I'm working on OSX 10.12.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: Have you checked a XML parser?

Comment: If the value to change is only present once in your file, a simple `sed -i 's/oldvalue/newvalue/' file.xml` is enough

Comment: `xmlstartlet` for instance?

Comment: Yes, I tried regexing the text and xmlstarlet, didn't succeed to replace just part of the value.

Comment: @Aserre: Do not recommend non `XML` aware tools `xml` updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xmlstarlet` with below `xpath` expression worked fine for me. The below expression does in-pace substitution (`-L` flag) of the `XML` file

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/Configure/Set[@name='my-elm']" -v '/dont/matter/THIS_ONE_NEED_TO_BE_UPDATED' xml-file
```

Drop the `-L` flag to check if the replacement is occurring properly, and once successful add the same.

Checked on `xmlstarlet (1.6.1)` on `OS X`

Though it is strictly **`NOT`** advised to use `sed` for `xml` updates, this below logic will work for you,

```
sed "s/\(<Set name=\"my-elm\".*>\)[^<>]*\(<\/Set.*\)/\1\/dont\/matter\/THIS_ONE_NEED_TO_BE_UPDATED\2/" xml-file
```

add the `-i.bak` for in-place substitution of the file.

Comment: Thanks. It works :) Two questions please. 1) Is there a way to do it without xmlstarlet? There are machines that don't have it installed 2) Is there a nice regex trick to update just the THIS_ONE_NEED_TO_BE_UPDATED part?

Comment: @StasS: Refer my update which should solve your problem,